# How can we add Batch information to the Bookkeeping report?

Tags: civireport, drupal-views, reports, batches

Batch name/title information does not show up in the columns available to the Bookkeeping report. Is there a way to add this?

As an alternative, we would also be open to creating a new bookkeeping "report" using Drupal Views, but I don't believe batch information is available to Views either.

Is there any way to include batch info in a bookkeeping report with available tools or will it require a custom report?

Answer (score 2):

I examined the code of the report and there is nothing batch-related in there. I have made some edits in the core Bookkeeping report that allow display of the Batch name/title on this report. I will file a JIRA ticket and link to the Github PR so it can be reviewed and if approved, added to core.

- [JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18092) ticket
- [GitHub PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7861) *on 4.7 (master)*

Comment: Bless you! I was just starting this last week or so looking for more batch related info.

Comment: @AllenHutchison The above is working for me -- feel free to test on your end and report back in JIRA.